# querying stopforumspam api with php always returns false

Tags: php

So I am using the stopforumspam API, and querying it like this as a test:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=122.180.206.92");
echo $data;
$check = strpos("<appears>yes</appears>", $data);
if ($check !== false)
{
    echo 'exists!';
    die();
}
else {
    echo "nope";
}
```

The $data it gets back from this example is this:

```
<response success="true">
    <type>ip</type>
    <appears>yes</appears>
    <lastseen>2015-07-06 09:50:52</lastseen>
    <frequency>4</frequency>
</response>
```

The strpos always returns false though, I can't figure out why?

Comment: Which one happens? Does it return false or the `$data` you showed?

Comment: I've edited it, I meant the strpos is always false, even though it should pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `strpos` incorrectly. The first parameter is your haystack and the second parameter is the needle.

http://php.net/strpos

Try this...

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=122.180.206.92");
echo $data;
$check = strpos($data, "<appears>yes</appears>");
if ($check !== false)
{
    echo 'exists!';
    die();
}
else {
    echo "nope";
}
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Second pair of eyes ;)